# Non-repetitive way of saying: access this object's member unless the object is null

Tags: c#, idioms, null-coalescing

Let's say I have a set of cars, where each car has a steering wheel.  I'd like to write a line of code that looks for a car in the set and returns its steering wheel, or returns null if the car isn't in the set.  Something like this:

```
Car found = // either a Car or null
SteeringWheel wheel = (found == null ? null : found.steeringwheel);
```

Is there a way to do this without using `found` and `null` twice in the expression?  I don't like the smell of the repetition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not an obvious improvement until c# 6 arrives, but you could hide the unpleasantness in an extension method until then.

```
void Main() {
    Car found = null;// either a Car or null
    SteeringWheel wheel = found.MaybeGetWheel();
}

public static class CarExtensions {
    internal static SteeringWheel MaybeGetWheel(this Car @this) {
        return @this != null ? @this.steeringwheel : null;
    }
}
```

Some people say that you shouldn't allow extension methods to be called on `null`, but it does work.  That's a style preference, not a technical limitation.

Comment: What's with the `@this` syntax?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I frequently do this with `ToString()`: `ToStringSafe()`.

Comment: `@this` just allows you to use "this" as an identifier instead of a keyword.

Comment: @dbc: Sometimes i use `string.Format("{0}", whatever)` to do that, as it tolerates nulls.

Answer (score 7):

You could wait a bit for C# 6.0, and then use null-conditional (a.k.a. safe navigation) operator, [`?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

```
SteeringWheel wheel = FindCar()?.steeringwheel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq you could do

```
var steeringwheel = cars.Where(c => c.name = "foo")
                        .Select(c => c.steeringwheel)
                        .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: `.Where` only works on `IEnumerable`.

Comment: True, but this "looks for a car in a set and returns either a steering wheel or null if the car isn't in the set"?